# Two files requiring each other in browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify

I have an issue with browserified JS where defined functions are returning undefined. I have a feeling it's because two of my files require each other. The files themselves are too big to put in this question so I'll simplify it here:

**file_A.js**

```
var fileB = require('./file_B.js');

var fileA = {};
module.exports = fileA;

fileA.functionOne = function() {
  // do something
  fileb.functionOne();
}

fileA.functionTwo = function() {
  // do something else
}
```

**file_B.js**

```
var fileA = require('./file_A.js');

var fileB = {};
module.exports = fileB;

fileB.functionOne = function() {
  // do something
  fileA.functionTwo();
}
```

File A can call the functions in File B no problem. But when I try to call the File A functions from File B, I just get `undefined`.

As I said, I have a feeling it's because they're requiring each other. But they do need to require each other. I haven't found anywhere in the docs that tells you not to do this, or how to avoid doing it if you have to.

Please help :(

Comment: Hadn't found this question. Thanks Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just going to cause pain.  Factor out whatever both files need into a separate file which doesn't require either File A or File B.